# Time piped processes individually

Tags: pipe, profiling

I have two processes, the output of the first is piped into the second. Is there any way to time each of the processes without having to serialize them?

Comment: What's your C++ question? Anyhow, my OS allows me to measure the used CPU cycles of two processes separately, maybe that's what you need? What has your research turned up by now? Lastly, what's the problem with serializing the two processes?

Comment: You would need to instrument the code of each process, or hack the shell (or whatever) that creates the processes and thus measure the time.

Comment: Of course, you can use `time foo| bash -c "time bar"` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your usage of "pipes" correctly, the following is a fairly general solution:

```
% mkfifo fifo 
% time foo > fifo &
% time bar < fifo &
```

You may be able to arrange for this using sh file descriptor trickery only.

> Is there any way to time each of the processes without having to
>   serialize them

You realize of course that since you tied them in a pipe this itself may serialize them?